# How can I sort this object by 'sortby' key which inside an array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
            {
                "AA": [
                    {
                        "key_name": "category",
                        "value": "long",
                        "sortby": "3"
                    }
                ],
                "BB": [
                    {
                        "key_name": "category",
                        "value": "long",
                        "sortby": "5"
                    }
                ],
                "CC": [
                    {
                        "key_name": "category",
                        "value": "short",
                        "sortby": "1"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

i Need to sort this object with the key "sortby" and that is inside an array ? Can any one help ?

Comment: No, you cannot sort objects.

Comment: why do you wan to sort an object?

Comment: @Bergi json data cant be sorted ?

Comment: @hasanmuntasir No, json objects don't have an order. Use an array instead.

Comment: even if you sort an object, its not guaranteed that it will stay in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make an array of the object keys, then sort it based on the value of the property inside the data and then map them into a new object:

```js
const data = {
  "AA": [
    {
        "key_name": "category",
        "value": "long",
        "sortby": "3"
    }
  ],
  "BB": [
    {
        "key_name": "category",
        "value": "long",
        "sortby": "5"
    }
  ],
  "CC": [
    {
        "key_name": "category",
        "value": "short",
        "sortby": "1"
    }
  ]
}

const res = Object.keys(data).sort((a, b) => {
  return parseInt(data[a][0].sortby, 10) - parseInt(data[b][0].sortby, 10)
});

const sortedData = {};

res.map(key => sortedData[key] = data[key]);

console.log(sortedData)
```

This isn't a good practice because objects are mutable in javascript and this implementation could cause you a lot of trouble in the future. The best way is to sort them and then push them into an array instead:

```js
const data = {
  "AA": [
    {
        "key_name": "category",
        "value": "long",
        "sortby": "3"
    }
  ],
  "BB": [
    {
        "key_name": "category",
        "value": "long",
        "sortby": "5"
    }
  ],
  "CC": [
    {
        "key_name": "category",
        "value": "short",
        "sortby": "1"
    }
  ]
}

const res = Object.keys(data).sort((a, b) => {
  return parseInt(data[a][0].sortby, 10) - parseInt(data[b][0].sortby, 10)
}).map(key => ({ key, value: data[key] }));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).sort(([key1, value1], [key2, value2]) => {
    return value1[0].sortby - value2[0].sortby
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution:

```js
var o = {
    "AA": [
        {
            "key_name": "category",
            "value": "long",
            "sortby": "3"
        }
    ],
    "BB": [
        {
            "key_name": "category",
            "value": "long",
            "sortby": "5"
        }
    ],
    "CC": [
        {
            "key_name": "category",
            "value": "short",
            "sortby": "1"
        }
    ]
}

o = Object.keys(o).sort(function(a, b){
    return parseInt(o[a][0].sortby) - parseInt(o[b][0].sortby);
}).reduce(function(acc, e){
    acc[e] = o[e]; return acc;
}, {})

console.log(o);
```

Comment: That's five lines! :P

Comment: Remove the \n :D